# which one is better, to identify a part of array with filter or for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a generic function which will retrieve a matched set of records from an array of objects. In this array, userId is sorted in ascending order.

```
var myArray = [
{userId: 1001, name: 'User1'},
{userId: 1002, name: 'User2'},
...
]
```

// Using 1st Type - _.filter - My preferred method. Apart from performance, I am using this method as a general practice in the code across the application hoping to move on to the latest methods.

```
function getRecords(n) {
    return _.filter(myArray, function(userRecord) {
        return userRecord.userId < n;
    })
}
```

//Using 2nd Type - Evaluating this option, whether this is more efficient than the previous one

```
function getRecords(n) {
    var filteredRecords = [];
    for(i=0;i < myArray.length; i++) {
          if (myArray[i].userId < n) {
              filteredRecords.push(myArray[i]);
          } else {
               break;
          }
    }
    return filteredRecords;
}
```

In the 2nd method, I know for loop will break immediately instead of iterating till the end of the array but on the other hand filter will go trough the entier list. Is filter really efficient in this scenario or is it correct to consider for loop? Please advise.

Comment: I think it will be better if you move your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and push the items until you reach the exit condition. Then return `true` and exit with it.

```
function getRecords(userId) {
    var temp = [];
    myArray.some(function(userRecord) {
        if (userRecord.userId >= userId) {
            return true;
        }
        temp.push(userRecord);
    });
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I liked this alternative as this also adopts latest methods. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is more efficient and the correct way to do it.

Filter is not appropriate in this case because it will continue running even after you know there won't be more matches.